# Comparison of two tables in Excel

Tags: excel

I am looking to do a comparison and sum the value afterwards

For example, if employee # matches in both tables then the formula should compare the sales and cancellation and give me the final number (Sales - cancellation). Please see picture below.
[image: Question picture]

I tried sumifs statement but it didn't seem to work

Comment: `=SUMIFS(TABLE1[SALES],TABLE1[EMPLOYEE #],1)-SUMIFS(TABLE2[CANCELATION],TABLE2[EMPLOYEE #],1)`?

Comment: No Scott, that doesn't work.

Comment: I hard coded `1` as the employee number you would need to change that to what you want to use.  You can point both of them at a cell to get what you want.

Comment: Figured it out. Used =SUMIFS(TABLE1[SALES],TABLE1[EMPLOYEE #] - SUMIFS(TABLE2[CANCELATION],TABLE2[EMPLOYEE #]. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood it correctly this is what you are asking for?:

[image: Picture of sheet]

This is the formula for cell c2:

```
 =B2-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$7,2,FALSE),0)
```